# How Can I Truncate HTML Table Cells using DataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have an HTML table where some of the cells have very long text, I'm therefore trying to truncate them to a limited number of characters and add an ellipsis if they exceed it. To make the table more interactive I'm using [datatables](https://datatables.net/), so I tried to follow [this datatables specific solution](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/134718/#Comment_134718) which uses their rendering features however it doesn't truncate values in my table. The example table where this isn't working can be found in [this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tp7rung/7/).

```js
function strtrunc(str, max, add) {
  add = add || '...';
  return (typeof str === 'string' && str.length > max ? str.substring(0, max) + add : str);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    targets: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
      if (type === 'display') {
        data = strtrunc(data, 10);
      }
      return data;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.truncate {
  max-width: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.3/dataRender/ellipsis.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table border="1" class="dataframe" id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>Dictionary ID</th>
      <th>GPPD ID</th>
      <th>ESAIL ID</th>
      <th>Common Name</th>
      <th>Settlement BMU ID</th>
      <th>National Grid BMU ID</th>
      <th>4C-Offshore ID</th>
      <th>WindPowerNet ID</th>
      <th>Wikidata ID</th>
      <th>Wikipedia ID</th>
      <th>Power-Technology ID</th>
      <th>EUTL ID</th>
      <th>EIC ID</th>
      <th>CfD ID</th>
      <th>JRC ID</th>
      <th>IAEA ID</th>
      <th>REPD ID (Old)</th>
      <th>REPD ID (New)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://osuked.github.io/Power-Station-Dictionary/objects/10000">10000</a></td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>MARK</td>
      <td>Rothes Bio-Plant CHP</td>
      <td>E_MARK-1, E_MARK-2</td>
      <td>MARK-1, MARK-2</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>48W000000MARK-1D</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://osuked.github.io/Power-Station-Dictionary/objects/10001">10001</a></td>
      <td>GBR1000377, GBR1000369</td>
      <td>DIDC</td>
      <td>Didcot</td>
      <td>T_DIDC1, T_DIDC2, T_DIDC4, T_DIDC3, T_DIDC1G, T_DIDC2G, T_DIDC3G, T_DIDC4G, E_DIDC1G, E_DIDC2G, E_DIDC3G, E_DIDC4G, T_DIDCB5, T_DIDCB6</td>
      <td>DIDC1, DIDC2, DIDC4, DIDC3, DIDC1G, DIDC2G, DIDC3G, DIDC4G, DIDC01G, DIDC02G, DIDC03G, DIDC04G, DIDCB5, DIDCB6</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>97165</td>
      <td>48W00000DIDC01G1, 48W00000DIDC02GZ, 48W00000DIDC03GW, 48W00000DIDC04GT, 48W000000DIDCB5C, 48W000000DIDCB6A</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://osuked.github.io/Power-Station-Dictionary/objects/10002">10002</a></td>
      <td>GBR1000374, GBR1000375</td>
      <td>ABTH</td>
      <td>Aberthaw B</td>
      <td>T_ABTH7, T_ABTH8, T_ABTH9, T_ABTH7G, T_ABTH8G, T_ABTH9G</td>
      <td>ABTH7, ABTH8, ABTH9, ABTH7G, ABTH8G, ABTH9G</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>97175</td>
      <td>48W0000000ABTH7Y, 48W0000000ABTH8W, 48W0000000ABTH9U, 48W000000ABTH7G2, 48W100000ABTH8GN, 48W000000ABTH9GX</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://osuked.github.io/Power-Station-Dictionary/objects/10003">10003</a></td>
      <td>GBR1000142</td>
      <td>COTPS</td>
      <td>Cottam</td>
      <td>T_COTPS-1, T_COTPS-2, T_COTPS-3, T_COTPS-4</td>
      <td>COTPS-1, COTPS-2, COTPS-3, COTPS-4</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>97778</td>
      <td>48W00000COTPS-1Q, 48W00000COTPS-2O, 48W00000COTPS-3M, 48W00000COTPS-4K</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://osuked.github.io/Power-Station-Dictionary/objects/10004">10004</a></td>
      <td>GBR0000174, GBR1000112</td>
      <td>DRAXX</td>
      <td>Drax</td>
      <td>T_DRAXX-1, T_DRAXX-2, T_DRAXX-3, T_DRAXX-4, T_DRAXX-5, T_DRAXX-6, T_DRAXX-10G, T_DRAXX-12G, T_DRAXX-9G</td>
      <td>DRAXX-1, DRAXX-2, DRAXX-3, DRAXX-4, DRAXX-5, DRAXX-6, DRAXX-10G, DRAXX-12G, DRAXX-9G</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>96842</td>
      <td>48W00000DRAXX-56, 48W00000DRAXX-64, 48W000DRAXX-10G9, 48W000DRAXX-12G3, 48W0000DRAXX-9GR</td>
      <td>INV-DRX-001</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I also tried the [ellipsis plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/ellipsis) made by datatables but this also didn't work. Following the alternatives in these ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67406187/how-to-truncate-a-field-data-in-datatable-and-add-more-options-towards-the-end)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809932/datatable-cell-string-truncate)[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752975/datatables-how-to-cut-string-and-add-and-put-the-full-string-in-tooltip)) questions was also unsuccessful.

Any help would be much appreicated.

Comment: Where do you actually use the truncate class?

Comment: Works for me if I do `<td class="truncate">T_DIDC1, T_DIDC2, T_DIDC4, T_DIDC3, T_DIDC1G, T_DIDC2G, T_DIDC3G, T_DIDC4G, E_DIDC1G, E_DIDC2G, E_DIDC3G, E_DIDC4G, T_DIDCB5, T_DIDCB6</td>`

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense, thank you both. I've now managed to get it working

Comment: We both say you are welcome ;) ? Feel free to delete the question

Comment: Haha I didn't realise you'd posted both replies. Thanks, will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had failed to set the `truncate` class in the `td` elements. This is now working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jb6xvuw4/8/).

Thanks to [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) for the help spotting this!

Comment: Hey what if I wanted to truncate all columns instead of a few?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ellipsis plugin, that seems a lot of code for such a simple task. I achieved a similar result with this:

```js
columns: [
    {
        data: 'description',
        render: data => {
            if(data.length > 350) {
                return `<span title="${data}">${data.substr(0, 350)}...</span>`;
            }
            return data;
        }
    },
]
```